# Using OpenCV homography with python error in method findHomography

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I have a goal to do `homography` on a live video by capturing my screen and processing it.

In order to do so, I took the code from this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html), and manipulated it inside a while loop as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from windowcapture import WindowCapture

# initialize the WindowCapture class
capture    = WindowCapture('My Window')
bar_img    = cv.imread('hammer.jpg',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

while(True):

    # get an updated image of the game
    screenshot = capture.get_screenshot()
    screenshot = cv.cvtColor(screenshot,cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    if bar_img is None or screenshot is None:
        print('Could not open or find the images!')
        exit(0)
        
    #-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector, compute the descriptors
    minHessian = 400
    detector = cv.SIFT_create()
    keypoints_obj, descriptors_obj = detector.detectAndCompute(bar_img, None)
    keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene = detector.detectAndCompute(screenshot, None)
    #-- Step 2: Matching descriptor vectors with a FLANN based matcher
    # Since SURF is a floating-point descriptor NORM_L2 is used
    matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv.DescriptorMatcher_FLANNBASED)
    knn_matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_obj, descriptors_scene, 2)
    #-- Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test
    ratio_thresh = 0.75
    good_matches = []
    for m,n in knn_matches:
        if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
            good_matches.append(m)
    #-- Draw matches
    img_matches = np.empty((max(bar_img.shape[0], screenshot.shape[0]), bar_img.shape[1]+screenshot.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    cv.drawMatches(bar_img, keypoints_obj, screenshot, keypoints_scene, good_matches, img_matches, flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    #-- Localize the object
    obj = np.empty((len(good_matches),2), dtype=np.float32)
    scene = np.empty((len(good_matches),2), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(len(good_matches)):
        #-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj[i,0] = keypoints_obj[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt[0]
        obj[i,1] = keypoints_obj[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt[1]
        scene[i,0] = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt[0]
        scene[i,1] = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt[1]
    H, _ =  cv.findHomography(obj, scene, cv.RANSAC)
    #-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    obj_corners = np.empty((4,1,2), dtype=np.float32)
    obj_corners[0,0,0] = 0
    obj_corners[0,0,1] = 0
    obj_corners[1,0,0] = bar_img.shape[1]
    obj_corners[1,0,1] = 0
    obj_corners[2,0,0] = bar_img.shape[1]
    obj_corners[2,0,1] = bar_img.shape[0]
    obj_corners[3,0,0] = 0
    obj_corners[3,0,1] = bar_img.shape[0]
    scene_corners = cv.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, H)
    #-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
    cv.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[0,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1])),\
        (int(scene_corners[1,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
    cv.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[1,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[1,0,1])),\
        (int(scene_corners[2,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
    cv.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[2,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[2,0,1])),\
        (int(scene_corners[3,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
    cv.line(img_matches, (int(scene_corners[3,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[3,0,1])),\
        (int(scene_corners[0,0,0] + bar_img.shape[1]), int(scene_corners[0,0,1])), (0,255,0), 4)
    #-- Show detected matches
    cv.imshow('Good Matches & Object detection', img_matches)
    cv.waitKey()

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break

print('Done.')
```

The class WindowCapture that I used uses win32gui to capture the window (maybe it makes a difference if I used it like this and not imread?)

I get the following error when I run the code:

```
C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\fundam.cpp:385: error: (-28:Unknown error code -28) The input arrays should have at least 4 corresponding point sets to calculate Homography in function 'cv::findHomography'
```

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: run your code in a debugger. look at the arguments to `findHomography`

Comment: There are less than 4 good-matches after keypoint extraction and matching in your inages